# My containerized tomcat web application doesn't see configured log4j2.xml

Tags: docker, containers, log4j2, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

My web application works fine with the created log4j2.xml file on an aws ec2 instance. But now I containerized it and it's running in ECS Fargate. I can see catalina logs in CloudWatch but not application specific logs that I configured in log4j2.xml file. log4j2.xml is located in a specific path like `/var/webapp/conf` and I've put the path in catalina.properties as `shared.loader=/var/webapp/conf`. Also, I see this ERROR in my catalina logs:

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.
```

Note: I don't want to change tomcat default logging. I'm just trying to send my application logs to the console as well, so I can see all the logs in one CloudWatch log stream.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration for log4j logging driver is not being recognised by your Fargate Task. The reason being, with Fargate tasks we can only setup some specific logging drivers via the Task Definition.

> Amazon ECS task definitions for Fargate support the awslogs, splunk, firelens, and fluentd log drivers for the log configuration.
>
> - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/AWS_Fargate.html

I recommend to use CloudWatch log driver:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/AWS_Fargate.html